# losing data when leaving scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope

I'm programming something in javascript and at one point I make an ajax call
I store the data in an object literal but when I leave the scope I lose the data (even in my object literal)

I don't understand what is happening here

```
var menusView = {
menusRep: null,
init: function () {
    this.menusRep = menusRepository;
    this.getMenus();
},
getMenus: function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'data/voordeelmenus.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            menusView.menusRep.menus = data;
            console.log(data);//console output: [object, object,...]
            console.log(menusView.menusRep.menus);//console output: [object, object,...]
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("error reading file: " + error);
        }
    });

    console.log(menusView.menusRep.menus); //console output: []

}
}

var menusRepository = {
menus: []
}
```

I think I included al the code that matters
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX and how you're using it.  The final console.log is firing before the AJAX call can complete, thus the data is not available when the console.log is made.

You have a few options as I see it.  You can use the returned data in the success callback, use another method within the success callback that processes the returned data, or you can set async to be false to process the AJAX request in a blocking fashion.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'data/voordeelmenus.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        menusView.menusRep.menus = data;
        console.log(data);//console output: [object, object,...]
        console.log(menusView.menusRep.menus);//console output: [object, object,...]
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("error reading file: " + error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That

```
 console.log(menusView.menusRep.menus); //console output: []
```

must be inside the ajax call because it is async. Otherwise it will always be empty

Edit : Keep in mind to call

```
 menusView.init();
```

Otherwise menusView.menusRep will be null

Hope it helps,

Dan

Comment: but the whole meaning behind the ajax call is that i can store the menus in the menusRepository. (so I would only need 1 ajax call) now it just gets rid of the data as soon as it leaves the scope

Comment: Then you should do inside the ajax call 

menusRepository = [something]

Comment: don't I do that at the

    menusView.menusRep.menus = data;

then?

Answer (score 0):

you have basically 2 lines

```
 $.ajax(...)
console.log(...)
```

the ajax line schedules an ajax call and a callback that will be called when the ajax call returns, but does not block: it is asynchronous.

After this has been scheduled, console.log is called but the menu has not yet been set. It will only be set later, when the ajax call returns.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is asynchronous.

So when your code execution reaches console.log(menusView.menusRep.menus); 
At that time your object did not receive any data.

Put your console.log(menusView.menusRep.menus);  inside success handler of ajax call